# How to migrate Orchard CMS to another Server

Tags: web-config, migration, orchardcms

I've already copied the files and the database to my new system. But now I don't know, in which web.config I find the sql server settings.

Any suggestions, links, etc?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Database server settings are usually found in $webapproot\App_Data\Sites\Default\Settings.txt